# Show all categories in left categories block menu in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.6

I have installed a prestashop theme that use cs blockcategories module to show the categories in the left bar. The problem is that I am not able to show all of them, because it shows a button "more".
Actually it looks like that
[image]

And I would like to get something like this:

[image]

How could I solve it?

Comment: This is a custom module by the theme author, so you can ether check at the module "Configure" page or to ask the author of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a configuration option you a have to modify the tpl file referred to left column of this custom module

you can find it in: modulefolder/views/templates/hook